# How to get records by month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have tried several solutions but the only one close enough to what i want is this

```
Sale.all.group("DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)").count
```

but it returns something like this

`{2016-07-01 00:00:00 UTC=>19, 2016-04-01 00:00:00 UTC=>70}`

is there something that can do this format?

`[month,number of sales]` ??

using postgres db.

Comment: have you tried `Sale.select("Month(created_at) as sale_month, count(*) as monthly_sales").group("Month(created_at)")` this will return `ActiveRecord` objects that respond to `sale_month` and `monthly_sales`. One of the best ways to determine if you are build a query correctly is to look at the sql generated you can do this by adding `to_sql` to the end of the query chain.

Comment: how to i use the returned sale::activerecord_relation?

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. What do you mean how do you use the `ActiveRecord::Relation`?

Comment: when u write that in console it just returns an activerecord::relation - no results back just the relation?

Comment: Okay if you really just want an `Array` add `.map{|record| [record.sale_month,record.monthly_sales] }` to my previous statement. Sorry overlooked postgres use EXTRACT as suggested below but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1):

try use [EXTRACT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html) function of postgresql,

in Rails code

```
results = Sale.all.group("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at").select("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) AS month, COUNT(*) as count")

p results[0].month if results[0]
```

Comment: how to i use the returned sale::activerecord_relation?

Comment: it returns an array of objects that has two fields, "month" and count". @PetrosKyriakou

Comment: added the missing quotation